# Reading CSV in Spark: how many readers?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

The following is example 5.13 of the "Learning Spark" book, on how to load a CSV with `textFile()` in Scala. How many `CSVReader`s and `StringReader`s will be created across the cluster? Is it one of each per line of text?

```
import java.io.StringReader
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader
...
val input = sc.textFile(inputFile)
val result = input.map{ line =>
  val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line))
  reader.readNext()
}
```

Comment: You're getting one instance per line of processed text but notice also the scope of your Readers are limited to the function you're passing to the .map() method hence they'll be garbage collected soon

Comment: @Max thanks, care to make that into an answer? Also, do you see a less wasteful alternative? Even if the readers are GC'd soon, it still seems like an awful lot of work to be doing for every single line.

Comment: Earlier in that chapter should have introduced you to mapPartitions as a means of reusing resources without the gc overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at page 107 of *Learning Spark* and see how to work on a per-partition basis. The .mapPartition() method will help you in reducing the cost of initialization operations, like creating an instance of your parser

```
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser

val inputData = sc.textFile(inputFile).cache()
inputData.mapPartitions(lines => {
     val parser = new CSVParser(',')
     lines.map(line => {
       parser.parseLine(line).mkString(",")
     })
   })
```